# php Call to a member function sentimentAnalysis() on a non-object

Tags: php, json, twitter, fatal-error, sentiment-analysis

I am in trouble with this error I know its expecting an object and have searched through the forums and failed when trying to apply fixes, this may be an easy fix by a few lines of code. I Appreciate if anyone has a bit of time to help fix this.

*Again this may be a duplicate but I have tried to apply fixes un-successfully*

Error is with the following line, I will include my whole script

```
 $response= $TwitterSentinmentAnalysis->sentimentAnalysis($twitterSearchParams);
```

> Fatal error: Call to a member function sentimentAnalysis() on a
>   non-object in
>   /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/infoCraft-miner/search_server.php
>   on line 48

```
<?php 

// The search terms are passed in the q parameter
// search_server.php?q=[search terms]
if (!empty($_GET['q'])) {

    // Remove any hack attempts from input data
    $search_terms = htmlspecialchars($_GET['q']);

    // Get the application OAuth tokens
    require 'app_tokens.php';

    //get the datumbox api key
    require 'config.php';
    require 'lib/TwitterSentimentAnalysis.php';

    $TwitterSentimentAnalysis = new TwitterSentimentAnalysis(DATUMBOX_API_KEY,
    TWITTER_CONSUMER_KEY,TWITTER_CONSUMER_SECRET,
    TWITTER_ACCESS_KEY,TWITTER_ACCESS_SECRET);

    // Create an OAuth connection
    require 'tmhOAuth.php';
    $connection = new tmhOAuth(array(
      'consumer_key'    => $consumer_key,
      'consumer_secret' => $consumer_secret,
      'user_token'      => $user_token,
      'user_secret'     => $user_secret
    ));

    // Request the most recent 100 matching tweets
    $http_code = $connection->request('GET',$connection->url('1.1/search/tweets'), 
        $twitterSearchParams=array('q' => $search_terms,
                'count' => 100,
                'lang' => 'en',
                'type' => 'recent'));

    // Search was successful
    if ($http_code == 200) {

        // Extract the tweets from the API response
        $response = json_decode($connection->response['response'],true);        
        global $TwitterSentinmentAnalysis;

         //Response to be sent to Sentiment API 
        $response= $TwitterSentinmentAnalysis->sentimentAnalysis($twitterSearchParams);    

        $tweet_data = $response['statuses']; 

        //Sending the Twitter API response(JSONP) direct to a local file
        $file = 'data.json';
        file_put_contents( 'data.json', json_encode($response)); 

        // Load the template for tweet display
        $tweet_template= file_get_contents('tweet_template.html');

        // Load the library of tweet display functions
        require 'display_lib.php';  

        // Create a stream of formatted tweets as HTML
        $tweet_stream = '';


        foreach($tweet_data as $tweet) {

            //if loop to change text color    
            $color=NULL;
            if($tweet['sentiment']=='positive'){            
                $color='#00FF00';
            }
            else if($tweet['sentiment']=='negative'){
                $color='#FF0000';
            }
            else if($tweet['sentiment']=='neutral'){
                $color='#FFFFFF';
            }

            // Ignore any retweets
            if (isset($tweet['retweeted_status'])) {
                continue;
            }

            // Get a fresh copy of the tweet template
            $tweet_html = $tweet_template;

            // Insert this tweet into the html
            $tweet_html = str_replace('[screen_name]',
                $tweet['user']['screen_name'],$tweet_html);
            $tweet_html = str_replace('[name]',
                $tweet['user']['name'],$tweet_html);        
            $tweet_html = str_replace('[profile_image_url]',
                $tweet['user']['profile_image_url'],$tweet_html);
            $tweet_html = str_replace('[tweet_id]',
                $tweet['id'],$tweet_html);
            $tweet_html = str_replace('[tweet_text]',
                linkify($tweet['text']),$tweet_html);
            $tweet_html = str_replace('[created_at]',
                twitter_time($tweet['created_at']),$tweet_html);
            $tweet_html = str_replace('[retweet_count]',
                $tweet['retweet_count'],$tweet_html);           

            // Add the HTML for this tweet to the stream

            $tweet_stream .= $tweet_html;

        }

        // Pass the tweets HTML back to the Ajax request
        print $tweet_stream;

    // Handle errors from API request
    } else {
        if ($http_code == 429) {
            print 'Error: Twitter API rate limit reached';
        } else {
            print 'Error: Twitter was not able to process that search';
        }
    }

} else {
    print 'No search terms found';
}   
?>
```

This is the file its calling the function from TwitterSentimentAnalysis.php

```
 public function sentimentAnalysis($twitterSearchParams) {
        $tweets=$this->getTweets($twitterSearchParams);

        return $this->findSentiment($tweets);
    }

    /**
```

Comment: Out of curiosity, what happens if you remove the `global $TwitterSentinmentAnalysis;` line?

Comment: @xjstratedgebx I get the following ---------Notice: Undefined variable: TwitterSentinmentAnalysis in /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/infoCraft-miner/search_server.php on line 44

Comment: +1 for a well asked question, especially including the full script causing the issue, and being quick to respond to a comment that ended up proving helpful to all parties.

Comment: @xjstratedgebx thanks for the helping!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks to me like there is a typo in your variable naming (which is why removing the global keyword is throwing a notice).

When you first define your object, it looks like this:

```
$TwitterSentimentAnalysis = new TwitterSentimentAnalysis(DATUMBOX_API_KEY,
    TWITTER_CONSUMER_KEY,TWITTER_CONSUMER_SECRET,
    TWITTER_ACCESS_KEY,TWITTER_ACCESS_SECRET);
```

So that's `$TwitterSentimentAnalysis`. However you're referencing it later as `$TwitterSentinmentAnalysis`. It's subtle, but there's an extra n in Sentiment in the second one.

Go ahead and adjust the variable name, remove the `global` line as it's unnecessary as far as I can tell (and a more uppity dev might go so far as to say global variables are bad form), and I think you're good to go.